# Calculate the zonal statistics for vector map over a classified image

Tags: qgis

I have a vector dataset that overlaps with a classified image with 5 classes. I want to perform zonal statistics to calculate the number of pixels fo each class in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Following link helped me to solve this. https://courses.gisopencourseware.org/mod/book/tool/print/index.php?id=551#ch1544